# Get attributes from XML with more than one namespaces

Tags: vba, namespaces, xmldocument

I have this XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="3.3" Serie="NG" Folio="55" Fecha="2017-08-02T20:08:58" FormaPago="99" SubTotal="5861.73" Descuento="778.38" Moneda="MXN" Total="5083.35" TipoDeComprobante="N" MetodoPago="PUE" LugarExpedicion="08400" Sello="yAfYBR0/bvvFgq/hNL+DSTTPt+kNtsE3DzxagXvG0M/alfaUrjp73IySCEBHIeo4nNF4uoscqnRoIowwfQPnNwC4LL6iD77rfykF2hq+i6VzqAlvbx0aawZUAcJpjNVWyS3zjfa3rYeU1TpNBrhSuU8r+4BoBz3jr1pB7yyCIm4JbwzNqy0TvTjD1XXnpy6v74+eqIoZqWZoi3CyiCqMS2B3FEfDMiXTfVlZ/3/evLYc5WvFPpBsm61I+SBID/rHhJvLQLjJDUX7Myt177N41xptITkIKQCJAIV6XN7mRGJTHKA3h3F7tSZaei8+LeONO9ZtlUZGw4dzLhrpNk/tuA==" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd">
    <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="BBBBBB" Nombre="S.A. de C.V." RegimenFiscal="601" />
    <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="AAAAAAAA" Nombre="AZUCENA SAN " UsoCFDI="P01" />
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="84111505" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="ACT" Descripcion="Pago de nómina" ValorUnitario="5861.73" Importe="5861.73" Descuento="778.38" />
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
        <nomina12:Nomina xmlns:nomina12="http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina12" Version="1.2" TipoNomina="O" FechaPago="2017-07-16" FechaInicialPago="2017-07-01" FechaFinalPago="2017-08-15" NumDiasPagados="15.000" TotalPercepciones="5861.73" TotalDeducciones="778.38" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/nomina12 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/nomina/nomina12.xsd">
            <nomina12:Emisor RegistroPatronal="Y6844621109" />
            <nomina12:Receptor Curp="SASA850203MDFNNZ06" NumSeguridadSocial="39058519115" FechaInicioRelLaboral="2012-09-14" Antigüedad="P254W" TipoContrato="01" Sindicalizado="No" TipoJornada="03" TipoRegimen="02" NumEmpleado="073" Departamento="VENTAS" Puesto="GERENTE TIENDAS" RiesgoPuesto="1" PeriodicidadPago="04" SalarioBaseCotApor="183.33" SalarioDiarioIntegrado="356.57" ClaveEntFed="DIF" />
            <nomina12:Percepciones TotalSueldos="5861.73" TotalGravado="5089.21" TotalExento="772.52">
                <nomina12:Percepcion TipoPercepcion="001" Clave="0001" Concepto="Sueldos" ImporteGravado="1026.69" ImporteExento="0.00" />
                <nomina12:Percepcion TipoPercepcion="020" Clave="0008" Concepto="Prima dominical" ImporteGravado="0" ImporteExento="78.36" />
                <nomina12:Percepcion TipoPercepcion="001" Clave="0020" Concepto="Vacaciones" ImporteGravado="1466.69" ImporteExento="0" />
                <nomina12:Percepcion TipoPercepcion="021" Clave="0009" Concepto="Prima Vacacional" ImporteGravado="0" ImporteExento="458.33" />
                <nomina12:Percepcion TipoPercepcion="038" Clave="0022" Concepto="Bonos" ImporteGravado="1000" ImporteExento="0" />
                <nomina12:Percepcion TipoPercepcion="028" Clave="0010" Concepto="Comisiones" ImporteGravado="1360" ImporteExento="0" />
                <nomina12:Percepcion TipoPercepcion="019" Clave="0007" Concepto="Horas extras" ImporteGravado="235.83" ImporteExento="235.83">
                    <nomina12:HorasExtra Dias="2" TipoHoras="01" HorasExtra="2" ImportePagado="235.83" />
                    <nomina12:HorasExtra Dias="1" TipoHoras="02" HorasExtra="1" ImportePagado="235.83" />
                </nomina12:Percepcion>
            </nomina12:Percepciones>
            <nomina12:Deducciones TotalOtrasDeducciones="122.73" TotalImpuestosRetenidos="655.65">
                <nomina12:Deduccion TipoDeduccion="002" Clave="0013" Concepto="ISR" Importe="655.65" />
                <nomina12:Deduccion TipoDeduccion="001" Clave="0012" Concepto="IMSS" Importe="122.73" />
            </nomina12:Deducciones>
        </nomina12:Nomina>
        <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/timbrefiscaldigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1" UUID="2A73927D-7E57-40C7-9A8B-2E062560AC9E" FechaTimbrado="2017-08-02T19:52:07" SelloCFD="yAfYBR0/bvvFgq/hNL+DSTTPt+kNtsE3DzxagXvG0M/alfaUrjp73IySCEBHIeo4nNF4uoscqnRoIowwfQPnNwC4LL6iD77rfykF2hq+i6VzqAlvbx0aawZUAcJpjNVWyS3zjfa3rYeU1TpNBrhSuU8r+4BoBz3jr1pB7yyCIm4JbwzNqy0TvTjD1XXnpy6v74+eqIoZqWZoi3CyiCqMS2B3FEfDMiXTfVlZ/3/evLYc5WvFPpBsm61I+SBID/rHhJvLQLjJDUX7Myt177N41xptITkIKQCJAIV6XN7mRGJTHKA3h3F7tSZaei8+LeONO9ZtlUZGw4dzLhrpNk/tuA==" NoCertificadoSAT="20001000000300022323" SelloSAT="FXfgRBNhWla+53sM4eGnMFbbmQFb6EIaWMt3GMaqXJn9XPxQ5DVNuz7oTJ+yUZV0ObM5myqzzsI4Zvx3g==" RfcProvCertif="EME000602QR9" />
    </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

And I need to get the values of some attributes, I can get attributes from the node cfdi:Comprobante, but when I try to read an attribute from tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital I get object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
        Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

    doc.Load("C:\Users\s_osr\Desktop\EjemplosCFDINomina12\HorasExtras\SIGN_XML_COMPROBANTE_3_0.xml")
    Dim managerdoc As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)

    managerdoc.AddNamespace("cfdi", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
    managerdoc.AddNamespace("tfd", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

    Dim Sello As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/@Sello", managerdoc).InnerText

    Dim SelloSat As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Complemento/tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital/@SelloSAT", managerdoc).InnerText
```

Sello is working, but I can´t get SelloSAT.

UPDATE:

Thanks to @Kaiido for the solution, the uri string for the second namespace:

managerdoc.AddNamespace("tfd", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital")

Comment: Yes VB .NET 3.5

Comment: I really don't know VBA, but shouldn't `managerdoc.AddNamespace("tfd", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)` be `managerdoc.AddNamespace("tfd", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital")` ? I guess (once again without knowing anything about it) that `doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI` is actually `cfdi`'s nameSpace's URI

Comment: OMG!, It Works. Thank you. I'm a noob using XmlDocument =S.

Comment: ;-) Glad I could figure something in a language I never read before. So in this case, beware `nomina12` has the same problem.